# Having a Function change variable in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, class, variables, object, python-3.4

I am working on a simple text based game and, I came across something that I do not know how to do. In my game you gain health, strength, defense, xp and levels as you progress through the game. I made it so whenever there is a battle I don't have to retype it all into the code, by making a function specifically for the battle. So when I want a battle to occur, I just type battle1() to have the battle sequence happen. The only problem with this is the stat variables change so often and in the code I have it set so if you use a potion and are attacked and your health goes above the max health for your character (which varies from level to level) it will be set to the max health you can have (for example, the player uses a potion when they have 15 health, and they're max health is 15, it would just stay at 15 health, rather than increasing to 17). Here is my code:

```
class player:
    def __init__ (self, name, health, strength, defense):
        self.__health = health
        self.__strength = strength
        self.__defense = defense
        self.__name = name
    def getName(self):
        return self.__name

    def getHealth(self):
        return self.__health

    def getStrength(self):
        return self.__strength

    def getDefense(self):
        return self.__defense

    def getPotion(self):
        return self.__potion

    def subHealth(self, num):
        self.__health -= num
        return self.__health

    def setHealth(self, h):
        self.__health = h


def main():

    name1 = input("What would you like your name to be?")
    print("Hello,", name1, "you are on a quest to save otis from the evil Dongus. You must slay him, or Otis will poop.")
    player1 = player(name1, 10, 2, 1)
    enemy = player("Rat", 15, 0, 0)
    print("Your stats are, health:", player1.getHealth(), "strength:", player1.getStrength(), "and defense:", player1.getDefense())
    print("Fight.")
    attack =input("Type 1 to attack.")

    if attack == "1":

        enemy.subHealth(player1.getStrength()-enemy.getDefense())
        **if enemy.getHealth()>15:
            enemy.setHealth(15)**
        print(enemy.getName()+"'s health is",enemy.getHealth())
        player1.subHealth(enemy.getStrength()-player1.getDefense())
        **if player1.getHealth()>10:
            player1.setHealth(10)**

main()
```

The parts that are bolded are the parts of the code I am talking about. So, is there any way to make it so, for example, when you're level 5 your max health is set to 15, rather than ten? Keep in mind, that during the battle your enemies damage you, so you can't just do player1.getHealth(). 
Thanks!

Comment: not an answer but you don't need those get and set methods, you can access attributes directly.

Comment: @Robbie: Just use the variables directly. Call it `health` instead of `__health`, then use `player1.health` instead of `player1.getHealth()` and `player1.health = foo` instead of `player1.setHealth(foo)`.

Comment: @Robbie: Also, even if you do need private variables (which you don't in this case), you don't want to use double underscores. Double underscores are only for methods that you need to hide from subclasses (so they can define a method with the same name without accidentally overriding yours). You may want to read [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the Pythons style guide, which explains all of this and more.

Comment: Ok makes sense, sorry I accidentally deleted my comment..

Comment: By the way, I'm not sure why someone downvoted you, because I think this is a reasonable question (being a novice doesn't make you stupid or lazy, it just makes you a novice). But you could definitely improve it by stripping out all of the irrelevant code (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and giving a more specific idea of what part of this you're stuck on.

Comment: Oh haha sorry, I joined another forum and they say to keep all the code in, no matter how irrelevant, and I guess I read the MCVE wrong >.<. I will do that once I get back from dinner.

Comment: @Robbie: StackOverflow is aiming to build a useful repository of answers—that way, those answers can be a top Google result in nicely searchable cases, and at least someone can point out that it's a duplicate in cases where search doesn't help. Figuring out which code is irrelevant (and verifying that you're right and can still demonstrate the problem) is how you do your part; running the code and making sure their answers actually work is how others do their part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, is there any way to make it so, for example, when you're level 5 your max health is set to 15, rather than ten?

Yes. You need to store a "max health" for the player, in addition to his "current health":

```
if player1.getHealth() > player.getMaxHealth()
    player1.setHealth(player.getMaxHealth())
```

---

As Padraic explains in a comment, you don't need getters and setters like this in Python, and it's generally considered bad style. So it would be better to write it like this:

```
if player1.health > player1.max_health:
    player1.health = player1.max_health
```

You can write this a little more concisely using `min`:

```
player1.health = min(player1.health, player1.max_health)
```

---

Also, if max health is something you can compute on the fly (maybe `10 + level`?), you can write a function for that, and call that function whenever you need it, instead of storing it as an extra attribute.

One of the neat things about Python is that you can start with an attribute, and change it to a computed value without having to turn it into a function, by using `@property`:

```
@property
def max_health(self):
    return 10 + self.level
```

Comment: Ok, almost all of that makes sense. Doesn't the min() function choose the smallest of the two values? What happens when the values are the same?

Comment: It returns the min value.  It doesn't matter if there is more than one minimum.

Comment: @Robbie: That's really the kind of thing you can test for yourself more quickly than you can ask. Just open your interpreter and type `print(min(2, 2))` and see what you get.

Comment: @Abarnert I did try it out, I just didn't understand why it worked.

Comment: Also I am getting an error as follows: "Basics/Game.py", line 100, in battle1
    enemy.Health = min(enemy.Health(), enemy.enemymaxHealth())
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable". Any ideas?

Comment: @Robbie: If you replace the getter function with a plain attribute, you don't call that attribute, just use it as a value. Look at my example again.

Comment: @abarnert but whenever I do that I get the error: in battle1
    enemy.subHealth = num+player1.Strength-enemy.Defense
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'method'.

Comment: @Robbie: Without seeing your code, it's hard to know exactly what you're doing wrong, but it looks like `Strength` is a regular attribute, while `Defense` is a method. You have to call the methods, and not call the members—or simplify things by making them all members so you don't need to worry about keeping them straight.

Comment: @abarnert I am confused on when something is an attribute, vs when it is a method. How do you set whether or not something is an attribute vs a method? For some reason I got rid of all the getters and setters in the code and for some reason, the majority of the functions I defined in "class player:" require to be called. This is an example of how I changed the functions:     def Strength(self): return self.__strength      (forgive me, I cannot format it in the comments :/). Yet, for some reason when I do "player1.strength" it requires me to call it.

Comment: @Robbie: I think you need to read the tutorial on [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html). But briefly (and loosely): a method is an attribute that's defined and called like a function. When you `def spam(self):`, that makes `spam` a method of every instance of your class. When you do `self.eggs = 0` in your `__init__` method, that makes `eggs` a normal attribute of every instance of your class.

Comment: @abarnert I think I need to take another class on Python. How would I got about changing all the methods to plain attributes in my code? I'm confused as in my code I have def Health(self): always, and I never did def Health(self) = self.Health. If I'm mistaken, shouldn't that mean I would always have to call the method with a ()? Only sometimes in my code it is needed. I don't really understand the article that well, I will try to read it when I'm less tired I suppose.

Comment: @Robbie: Just get rid of the `def Health(self):` method entirely, and change the code that does `self.__health = health` to `self.health = health`. Then you have an attribute `health`. Which you can access form inside as `self.health`, or from outside as `player1.health`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @abarnert That makes complete sense. Everything in the code looks so much simpler :). Almost everything is working fine now but, I will ask it in another question.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the responsibility to the player, e.g.:

```
def changeHealth (self, delta):
    self.__health += delta

    maxHealth = 10 if self.__level < 5 else 15
    if self.__health > maxHealth:
        self.__health = maxHealth
    elif self.__health < 0
        self.__health = 0
```